# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when running Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

Why do I get the following warnings, and how can I get rid of them?

**Warnings:**

> (node:26771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
>
> (node:26771) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zeroexit code.

**Code:**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://dn.se", { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
    var output = page.evaluate(() => {
        return;
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

**Environment:**

- macOS High Sierra
- Node v8.5.0
- Puppeteer: 1.9.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), as it returns a promise:

```
var output = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return;
});
```

Make sure you are using [`process.on('unhandledRejection')`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) to listen for unhandled promise rejections and to gracefully close the browser if such an event should occur:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
  browser.close();
});
```

Your final code should end up looking like this:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.error('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
    browser.close();
  });

  await page.goto('https://dn.se', {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });

  var output = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return;
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: How do i continue to run the script on unhandledRejection?